# Grant direct access for Azure Active Directory security group to SharePoint Online list item using a Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

We found examples for granting permissions to a list item using the REST API by email address or SharePoint Group ID. We haven't found an example of how to add an Azure AD security group to a SharePoint list item. Anyone aware if this is possible and what the format would be for the POST HTTP action in the flow to accomplish this? You can manually give direct access to an Azure AD security group using the user interface for the list item permissions.

Here are instructions for applying a specific user or SharePoint group:

https://www.annajhaveri.com/power-automate/set-unique-permissions-for-item-in-sharepoint-using-power-automate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are unable to grant access directly to Azure AD group in flow with rest api.

The workaround is to add the azure ad group to sharepoint first, then use following uri to get the group:

`_api/web/SiteGroups/getbyname('AzureAdGroup')`

Comment: We'll try adding our Azure AD security groups to the SharePoint site collection visitor group and then grab them using their SharePoint Site Group name. Thanks for the cofirmation. We may also look at how Nintex Workflow Cloud handles permissions. There should be an easier way to manage direct permissions on a list item than using REST calls using flows! I think Plumsail provides some actions, but haven't researched if they allow direct access to Azure AD security groups for direct permissions. Odd you can do it in the user interface but not through a flow or the REST API.